# TableView resizing - only when button clicks

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift

I am having some issues with my table view resizing - As it looks when the page loads :

[image]

And then once the button is clicked

[image]

As you can see, the button click renders the table to be of the correct size - how can I achieve this from the outset - as it makes it look much neater

My code for the class is as follows;

```
//
//  FirstViewController.swift
//  Intercultural Collaboration
//
//  Created by Ricki Lambert on 06/10/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 com.kentapps. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class QuizViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate{

    var countries:Array<Answer> = [];
    var selected = -1;
    var positionOfSelected = 1;

    @IBOutlet var next: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!


    @IBAction func next(sender: AnyObject) {

    }

    func checkOkToProceed() -> Bool {
        positionOfSelected = 1;
        var result = false;

        for answer in countries{
            if(answer.selected){
                result = true;
                break;
            }
            positionOfSelected++;
        }
        return result;
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

        if(sender.tag > 0 && !self.checkOkToProceed()){
            //the user has not selected an answer so
            //we need to show them a prompt

            var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Unanswered Question", message: "Please select an answer!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil);
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();

        tableView.reloadData();
        //load answers to countries array
        self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = false;

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.countries.count;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CountryCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.countries[indexPath.row].answerName;
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;

        let countryImage = String(self.countries[indexPath.row].answerName) + ".png";
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: countryImage);


        if(countries[indexPath.row].selected){
            let imageName = "tick.png";
            let image: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: imageName));
            cell.accessoryView = image;
        }else{
            let image: UIImageView = UIImageView();
            cell.accessoryView = image;
        }

        tableView.sizeToFit();
        return cell;
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

        countries[indexPath.row].setSelected(true);

        if(selected != -1){
            countries[selected].setSelected(false);
        }
        selected = indexPath.row;
        tableView.reloadData();
    }

    func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {

        if (buttonIndex == 0) {
            //Do something
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused on why you call `tableView.sizeToFit()` after each cell creation in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? Did you try to call `sizeToFit()` in `viewDidLoad` just after `tableView.reloadData()`?

Comment: yes and it doesn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: Try to call `sizeToFit` in `viewDidAppear` to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: That works, except you briefly see the bottom bit - and then it disappears

Comment: Then use `viewWillAppear`

Comment: view will appear does not work

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue. Here is an elegant solution:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

Comment: Did you put it into `viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: I did - yes - after super.viewDidLoad

Comment: Did you eliminate `sizeToFit`? -- As an alternative, you might want to consider calculating the desired frame of the table view based on the cell height and number of countries.